# Prove that $5$ divides $3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, divisibility

> Prove that $5$ divides $3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}$

I tried to prove the result by induction but I couldn't.

The result is true for $n=1$.

Suppose that the result is true for $n$ i.e $3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}=5k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. We study the term

$$3^{3n+4}+2^{n+2}=3^{3n+1}3^3+2^{n+1}2$$

I tried to prove that that the difference is a multiple of $5$.

$$3^{3n+1}3^3+2^{n+1}2-3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}=2(3^{3n+1}\cdot 13+2^n)$$

Therefore it's enough to prove that $3^{3n+1}\cdot 13+2^n$ is a multiple of $5$. But if I do again this method applied to this "new problem" is get something similar. I think that there exist a different method to do this using induction.

Comment: The obvious alternative solution would be modular arithmetic and Fermat's little theorem. But somehow I always feel like that would be cheating with a problem like this. It takes away all the fun.

Comment: Not necessary (see answer below)

Comment: @Arthur: to me the obvious solution is modular arithmetic and induction (no Fermat required). (See my answer below.) I don't see why that is cheating in any way. I don't see any merit in trying to avoid modular arithmetic. (See all the other answers below.) Please enlighten me if you do.

Comment: Let $u_n=3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}$. Observe that, $$u_{n+1}=2(3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1})+3^{n+1}25=2u_n+3^{n+1}25\implies u_{n+1}\equiv 2u_n\pmod{5}$$Now apply induction on $n$.

Answer (score 10):

Hint :

$$3^{3n+4}+2^{n+2}=27\times 3^{3n+1}+2\times 2^{n+1}=2\times(3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1})+25\times 3^{3n+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your approach works if you just subtract once more:
$$
3^{3n+4} + 2^{n+2} - 2\cdot 5k\\
= 27\cdot 3^{3n+1} + 2\cdot 2^{n+1} - 2(3^{3n+1} + 2^{n+1})\\
= 25\cdot 3^{3n+1}
$$
and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

$3 (27^{n})+2 (2^{n}) $ is equal to your value,so $3 (2^{n})+2 (2^{n})=5( 2^{n}) $ has equal remainder (as dividing by 5) with the previous value because 27 has the same remainder ( with respect to 5) as 2.  so it is proved.

Comment: This is the best solution of all.

Comment: I'm glad you liked it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why people want to avoid modular arithmetic in solving problems like this. Fermat's little theorem is not required:

Let $f(n) = 3^{3n+1}$ and $g(n) = 2^{n+1}$. We want to prove that $f(n) \equiv -g(n) \;(\mathrm{mod}\;5)$. When $n=0$ this says that $3 \equiv -2\;(\mathrm{mod}\;5)$ which is true. Noting that $f(n+1) = 27f(n) \equiv 2f(n) \;(\mathrm{mod}\;5)$ and $g(n+1) = 2g(n)$, we have that, if $f(n) \equiv -g(n) \;(\mathrm{mod}\;5)$, then also

$$f(n+1) \equiv 2f(n) \equiv -2g(n) \equiv -g(n+1) \;(\mathrm{mod}\;5)$$

and so what we wanted to prove follows by induction.

Comment: This is the right way to do this problem.

Comment: ... for those familiar with modular arithmetic

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: you are almost certainly much more familiar than I am with what is currently taught. I find it incredible that students might be taught Fermat's little theorem prior to modular arithmetic. I learnt modular arithmetic at school but didn't learn Fermat's little theorem until my first year at university: but that was a long time ago. Why teach a rather specialised result before going into the basics of division?

Comment: I don’t know if OP knows modular arithmetic, let alone Fermat’s little theorem; I gather that OP was looking for answers merely with induction, which there are here

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: OK: good point.

Answer (score 1):

$$3^{3n+4}+2^{n+2}=3^{3n+1}\cdot 3^{3} +2^{n+1}\cdot 2\\
=(5k-2^{n+1})\cdot 3^{3}+2^{n+1}\cdot 2\\
=2^{n+1}(2-27)+5k\cdot 27=-2^{n+1}\cdot 25+5k\cdot 27\\
=5(-2^{n+1}\cdot 5+27k)$$ which is divisible by $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Or we could just expand and rearrange$$
\begin{align}
3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1} 
&= 3\cdot27^n + 2\cdot2^n \\
&= 3\cdot(25+2)^n +  2\cdot2^n  \\
&= 3\left(5k+2^n \right) + 2\cdot 2^n  \tag{Using Binomial Theorem}\\
&= 5\cdot k'+3\cdot2^n+2\cdot2^n  \\
&= 5\cdot k'+5\cdot 2^n \\
\end{align}
$$
Hence proved

Answer (score 0):

try this
$$3^{3n+1}3^3+2^{n+1}2-3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}=3^{3n+1}\cdot26+2^{n+1}$$

$$3^{3n+1}\cdot26+2^{n+1}=3^{3n+1}\cdot25+3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}$$

since $3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}=5k$

$$3^{3n+1}\cdot25+3^{3n+1}+2^{n+1}=3^{3n+1}\cdot25+5k$$

the difference is divisable by $5$